# How to update selected attribute of entity in symfony2?

Tags: symfony, crud, symfony-forms

I have a User entity. It has an attributes name, email and password. 
I already created UserType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
            ->add('name', 'text', ['attr' => ['placeholder' => 'name']])
            ->add('password', 'repeated', [ 'type' => 'password', 'first_options' => array('label' => 'Password', 'invalid_message' => 'Passwords don\'t match.',),
                'second_options' => array('label' => 'Confirm Password'), 'invalid_message' => 'Passwords do not match'])
            ->add('email', 'email', ['attr' => [ 'placeholder' => 'Email']])
    ;
}
```

And I already created a registration form for the user, and it is working perfectly in inserting data. What I'm trying to do is to make two edit forms, one for name and the other is for email.
And when clicking the edit link for name or email it would show a modal form.
I already have created modal in the twig.

I don't know how to create separate forms for name and email for editing and update the entity.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a similar project using FOSuserbundle, it will save you lot of time, give it a try!